# How (and when) properly initialize camera in Windows Phone 8.1 (RT)

Tags: windows-phone-8, camera, navigation, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I'm writing simple WP app, that can work with images stored in a device or image taken by a camera right in my app. I'm maybe confused with navigation and camera initializing. There is a MainPage in the app where are buttons to select camera or library. Camera button just navigates to the CameraPage like this:

```
private void CameraButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ...

        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(CameraPage));
    }
```

And then I initialize camera in CameraPage OnNavigatedTo:

```
protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        ...

        cameraCapture = new CameraCapture();
        PreviewElement.Source = await cameraCapture.Initialize(Dispatcher);
        await cameraCapture.StartPreview();

        ...
    }
```

And CameraCapture initialization:

```
public async Task<MediaCapture> Initialize(CoreDispatcher dispatcher)
    {
        var cameraID = await GetCameraID(Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel.Back);
        // Create MediaCapture and init
        mediaCapture = new MediaCapture();
        await mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings
        {
            StreamingCaptureMode = StreamingCaptureMode.Video,
            PhotoCaptureSource = PhotoCaptureSource.VideoPreview,
            AudioDeviceId = string.Empty,
            VideoDeviceId = cameraID.Id
        });

        mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.PrimaryUse = Windows.Media.Devices.CaptureUse.Video;

        this.dispatcher = dispatcher;

        var maxResolution = mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.GetAvailableMediaStreamProperties(MediaStreamType.Photo).Aggregate((i1, i2) => (i1 as VideoEncodingProperties).Width > (i2 as VideoEncodingProperties).Width ? i1 : i2);
        await mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.SetMediaStreamPropertiesAsync(MediaStreamType.Photo, maxResolution);

        imgEncodingProperties = ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg();

        return mediaCapture;
    }
```

The problem is - when I tap on the CameraButton on my MainPage, the app freezes on the MainPage until camera isn't initialized and then is the CameraPage loaded. What is the best approach to deal with this? Should I just move content from CameraPage to MainPage (so initialize camera on the MainPage and take a photo here)? Or there is a better way - like some event on the CameraPage? Tapping another button on the CameraPage to initialize camera would be so annoying for both me and user :)

Comment: If you want to do something with your preview, then better place probably would be *Page.Loaded* event. I think that in your case more importnat is not when to initialize the camera, BUT when release it - what happens when the user navigates away, hits Start button, and so on.

Comment: I've solved suspending already - it works well - I'm releasing resources (camera) on supending and reloading camera on resuming. It works on emulator and my device well. As I said, problem is with initializing camera when tapping button on the MainPage. Don't get me wrong - it works, but it freezes on the MainPage for a while (1-2 sec.) until camera is initialized. When CameraPage is loaded, it works fine then.

Comment: I think the problem may be that it not *freezes* the page (you can react) but it just *awaits* when Initializing is complete - you await the result, so further code is not processed until init is finished. Initializing may take some time, maybe you can put some king of a progress indicator to inform the user that camera is being initialized. Or it's something different?

Comment: Can you also show *CameraCapture* class and it's methods (especially *Initialize*)? It looks similar, but it seems that it's your implementation.

Comment: I would like to do it, but I don't know how. When I tap CameraButton it freezes. I used simple test - hide this button when I click it - but nothing has changed, because app is "frozen" until cam is initialized and CamPage fully loaded... When I tap CameraButton, it doesn't react at all :( and this.Frame.Navigate isn't awaitable.

Comment: Initialization code added. It's code from a tutorial mixed (I guess) with your code Romasz :)

Comment: Maybe you can move your camera initialization once the CameraPage is loaded?

Comment: And how can I do that, please? Because Page_Loaded event is fired BEFORE a page is "rendered on screen" - same result here... App freezes on the MainPage, loaded event is fired, camera loaded and AFTER THAT is CameraPage "really loaded" from user perspective. Same result as using "OnNavigatedTo".

Comment: You are right with the Loaded event. I've also tried to marshall the initialization to ThreadPool but it seems that there is also a little lag before the user can see the page.